# Mechanism of an epoxide ring opening with trimethylaluminium

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Am I right that there is a rearrangement reaction here? After coordinating the lewis acid to the oxygen, how do I come up with the correct rearrangement step?

Comment: Looks like it is partially a rearrangement to me.